# broken-pipe sometimes happens. This error is repeated (infinitely repeated) and then tomcat reboots

Tags: spring, tomcat, freebsd, broken-pipe

I'm using FreeBSD + spring Framework + Tomcat.
broken-pipe sometimes happens. This error is repeated (infinitely repeated) and then tomcat reboots.
  Is the tomcat setting a problem? Or is there another problem?

The data is retrieved through an AJax call, which often occurs when the data is large.

--- ERROR LIST ---

```
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.j==> [201911231438424]==============================================
→ TITLE  : ErrorException Occurred
→ DATE   : 2019-11-23 14:38:424
→ URL    : /--
→ METHOD : POST
→ TYPE   : application/json, text/plain, */*
→ MEMBER : --
→ AGENT  : InforexAgent--, appProvider=google, appChnl=0)
→ REF    : https://--
→ ERROR  : org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:356)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter$XServletOutputStream.write(ExpiresFilter.java:1010)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2039)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1051)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:953)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:285)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        ...
        ...
        ...
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1306)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:496)
        ...
        ...
        ...
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)

==============================================[201911231438424] <==

2019-11-23 14:38:33.491 ERROR 73119 --- [http-nio-8081-exec-10] c.i.y.c.e.base.ExceptionController       :
```